# Cannot insert null on identity column when using upsert in Copy data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

This is my first post so please bear with me.

- In Azure Data Factory pipeline I'm using a Copy Data action.
- I have my source table(.parquet file) and my target table.
- I want to use Upsert in Sink to copy data to the target table.
- The target table has a field ID which is a primary key and has identity to increment with 1.
  The column that I compare key data is of course another column. I do all the mapping and remove the mapping between ID columns.
- When I run this I get an error that I cannot insert null in ID. I tried to do a full insert and it works without the ID but when I change to Upsert it fails.  The issue was also raised  to Microsoft help center and indeed it's a bug regarding the Upsert logic. I was advised to create custom Stored procedure to perform the Upsert using Merge statement as workaround.
- EDIT: info about the source and the sink
  Source:
  Source dataset * :  data.parquet
  File path type: Wildcard file path
  Recursively: Enabled
  Sink:
  Sink dataset* : data_table
  Write Behaviour: Insert ( this is where I want to change to Stored procedure)
  Bulk Insert table lock: No
  Table option: None
  Pre-copy script: delete from db.targettable

All other settings are empty/unticked.

> Basically what i want to do is if I have a matching set of keys from the source to the target then it will be an update, otherwise if I don't find matching it will be an insert.Now, i want to use store procedure, where I want define what are the key columns to use as an "upsert" in the target table.

I have no experience in writing store procedures, if some of you kindly explain how this procedure should look like. Below is kinda what i wrote:

```
create procedure [db].[prc_LoadData]
@column1 NVARCHAR(19),
@column2 NVARCHAR(10),
@column3 NVARCHAR(10),
@column4 DATE,
@column5 DATE 
AS
BEGIN
Select * from db.targettable where column1=@column1,
Select * from db.targettable where column2=@column2,
Select * from db.targettable where column3=@column3,
Select * from db.targettable where column4=@column4,
Select * from db.targettable where column5=@column5
END
```

Comment: You may want to check out the [offical MERGE doc that the MSFT staff is talking about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) first. Currently the scope of your question is too broad if you ask people to write the stored procedure for you.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the information about the source and the sink in the `copy data` activity of your pipeline??

Comment: I've added the details about the source and the sink @SaideepArikontham-MT

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures allow you to execute the set of SQL statements without having to write all those statements each time you want to use these statements. The syntax will be as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure_name> <parameters to be passed>
AS
BEGIN
--sql query
END
GO
```

`MERGE` statement uses the data from source table to do operations such as insert, update or delete on the destination table based on a matching condition. Since your requirement is as shown below:

> Basically what I want to do is if I have a matching set of keys from
> the source to the target then it will be an update, otherwise if I
> don't find matching it will be an insert. Now, I want to use store
> procedure, where I want define what are the key columns to use as an
> "upsert" in the target table.

You can use the `MERGE` statement inside the stored procedure in the following way to insert if there is no match and update if there is a match in destination table. The following is a small example of using merge statement with stored procedure.

- My demo table:

[image]

- My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsertPlayer_data]
    @gid     int
  , @gamename    varchar(100)


AS
MERGE INTO dbo.player_data AS tgt
USING
  (SELECT @gid) AS src (id)
  ON tgt.Id = src.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE        
    SET
        gname = @gamename
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (
      id
    , gname
  ) VALUES (
      @gid
    , @gamename
  );
```

- I am using the merge statement using the matching condition as `id`. When it matches with the `id` in my destination table, I updated `gname`
- When the matching condition is false, I have inserted the table values.

You can use the format of the above stored procedure and make necessary changes for it to work accordingly with respect to your source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a known bug in Azure Data Factory that was fixed in the past week. Microsoft was notified of the issue in May 2022 and began rolling out the fix this week.

Details are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/856280/cannot-insert-null-on-identity-column-when-using-u.html)